# Why am I seeing these packets trying to connect to my ubuntu 20.04 box

Tags: networking, vpn, cloud

I have just updated to ubuntu 20.04 and was checking that everything was working as expected.  I noticed these odd packets (tcpdump) and wondered if anyone can explain why I am seeing them.  The netblock is owned by Oracle and it looks like they are trying to initiate some sort of secure connection.  They are very persistent - every 10 seconds or so

132.145.7.57.isakmp > xxxxxxxx.yyyyyyy.co.uk.isakmp: isakmp 1.0 msgid 00000000 cookie ed4a1aa05be9d580->0000000000000000: phase 1 I ident: [|sa] (len mismatch: isakmp 1956/ip 1432)

Is there anything cloud based that I am missing related to Ubuntu 20.04 ?

Comment: https://community.cisco.com/t5/security-documents/isakmp/ta-p/3113882

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out.  I had created an oracle cloud account at some time in the past and there was a VPN configuration which was still active even though I don't have any virtual machines running there.  Nothing Ubuntu specific

Sorry